# Bootstrap Tooltip alignment issue after update?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using JQuery 2.1.4 and Bootstrap 3.3.5 to create a tooltip on an element.  It works great until it's time to update the tooltip via JavaScript.

Once the tooltip's text has been updated, the position of the tooltip is changed and it's hard to get it to display (gotta mouse over the very bottom of the target element).

I change the tooltip text like so:

```
$("#unsavedChanges").
                attr('title', "Changed Tooltip.  Extra annoying when it's kinda long like this one here.").
                tooltip('setContent').tooltip('fixTitle');;
```

I've also tried adding data-container="body", but since this particular element is "position:fixed", the tooltip is no longer attached to the element and moves independently when scroll with the mouse wheel.

Here's a fiddle (the red element is the one with the problem): https://jsfiddle.net/5dpzaqgo/

Any idea what's causing this and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the issue is only there is not enough space in the corner for the tooltip to show up. If you change `left:100px` on your `div.style-switcher-btn-3`, it will be resolved.

You can check out a working example in [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/oLkuat84/10/). I know you may not want to have your button group to be 100px away from the left corner, but you would see the issue with this example. It also works when you show the tooltip on the bottom of the element using `data-placement="bottom"`.

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for figuring that out.  Wish there was a way to fix that.  I'll probably just live with short tooltips in that position.

Can I ask how you went about trouble shooting that?  Just kept messing with values or was it more scientific than that?  :)  Thanks!

Comment: well, I had almost the same issue in the past. But the way that I figured that out in the first place, after checking bootstrap documentation and examples, was to look in to elements box sizing values in development tools. Then I saw that there was no room for the button to show up in the right place. I remember I could solve it by finding the class of tooltip container and reposition it in jQuery.